# Is 'glance' a colloquialism?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary, formality

I am writing a paper titled: "A glance at Milnor-Thurston homology for metric spaces".

Does this title sound right? Or is it too informal?

Is the article 'a' at the beginning correct?

Comment: The "A" at the beginning is good. Keep it, if only for the ambiguity it avoids. Can't say if this sounds informal though; I think not.

Comment: Personally, I think using "A glance at" instead of (for example) "An analysis of" or "A summary of" is pretentious and silly.

Comment: Unless your paper is very short, _look_ would be better than _glance_. It's also likely _the_ Milnor-Thurston homology. I presume you have your reasons for not using title case.

Comment: I have never seen "title case" in mathematical papers.

Comment: Paper has 7 pages, so it is not very long. I think that most authors do not use "the" with "homology". For example: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1979-074-02/S0002-9939-1979-0524318-6/  or "https://msp.org/pjm/1998/186-2/". Somebody explained me that we don't use "the" because these terms are so standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A glance at Milnor-Thurston homology for metric spaces

- 'A' is necessary for glance. Otherwise it would sound like an imperative, that you're asking the reader to look at something.
- 'the' is needed for an object (in mathematics or otherwise). But a theory is more abstract, and doesn't require one. And 'Milnor-Thurston homology' is not an object, more of a 'way to do things'.
- 'a glance', the word itself, is not colloquial or informal at all. You won't find boys on the playground using it, more likely in belles lettres. But what you're really looking after is what sort of tone it sets for you paper. The word 'glance' makes me expect that your paper is expository or explanatory or philosophical, that it probably won't break any new theoretical ground or introduce a new symbolic technique. A paper with such a title would more likely be found in the Mathematical Intelligencer rather than Algebraic Topology. That is a nuance to the word 'formal' which has a different nuance in mathematics than in literary style.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. Then probably I will leave "A glance". The paper is not expository, but it solves a little problem related to this homology theory (which is just a generalization of my previous result to all metric spaces). 

But I am confused with "the". Somebody explained me that we don't use this article with all these "homology theories", because they are standard notions. And I see that many authors actually don't do it: e.g. http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1979-074-02/S0002-9939-1979-0524318-6/, https://msp.org/pjm/1998/186-2/

Comment: I just googled for examples. You're right. 'the' is wrong here. When referring to a generic theory, you don't use an article. When referring to a mathematical object you do (I am unfamiliar with the topic so parsed it as an object).

Comment: If you _solve_ a problem, that's not really a 'glance'. You're actually analyzing some very fine details. A 'glance' is metaphorical (for a quick look). If a metaphorical feel is what you want then use it.

Comment: The reason I used "glance" was because the problem I solve is a very special case of a general problem. But maybe you can suggest a better word.

Comment: I think what you said is perfect... 'A special case of  Milnor-Thurston...'. 'glance' just seems too much like a non-technical article.